# PHP - Connection failed to PostgreSQL database in virtual machine

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database in a virtual machine, through a php script, but being unsuccessful.

I execute the php from the host (Windows 8.1) and the postgresql is at the virtual machine (Debian 8.6). I use VirtualBox.

The error output from the browser is:

Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "10.0.2.15" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? in C:\xampp\htdocs\pg_test.php on line 11

with line 11 being `pg_connect($conn_string)`.

The parameters passed to `pg_connect($conn_string)`are:

```
$host = "host=10.0.2.15";
$port = "port=5432";
$dbname = "dbname=postgres";
$user = "user=user_switch";
$password = "password=switch";
$conn_string = "$host $port $dbname $user $password";
pg_connect($conn_string);
```

I use `host=10.0.2.15` because I checked (with ifconfig) that the guest has the ip `10.0.2.15`.

I modified the files `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf`, to include the lines:

pg_hba.conf:

`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust`

postgresql.conf:

`listen_addresses = '*'`

In `iptables` I added the rule `-A INPUT -p tcp -m cp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`

I also tried by disabling the firewall on the Windows host.

In some places they say its SELinux blocking the connection, but I don't have it installed in the guest.

I am able to succesfully connect to the database using the user "user_switch" in the guest with the command `psql -d postgres -U user_switch -W -h localhost`, in which it prompts me for the password.

Thanks in advance, please feel free to ask about more specifications I may have forgotten.

Comment: Can you connect from the guest machine using `psql -d postgres -U user_switch -W -h 10.0.2.15`?

Comment: @pietrop It gives this error: `psql: FATAL: there is no line in pg_hba.conf  for <<10.0.2.15>>, user <<user_switch>>, database <<postgres>>, SSL inactive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host and guest must be on the same network. You have to assign proper address to both, for example `192.168.56.1` on host and `192.168.56.101` on guest. For security reasons, you should remove the line allowing connection from any IP (`0.0.0.0/0`) and add the following line to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host  all  all  192.168.56.0/24  trust
```

and restart PostgreSQL. This allows any connection attempt to guest from `192.168.56.x`.

Comment: It still doesn't let me to connect from the host, but in the guest I could connect with the command from your comment.

Comment: @DeRipper what's the address of the host machine?

Comment: It has `192.168.1.37` for the wi-fi connection and `192.168.56.1` for the Virtual Box Host-Only Network. Included in the pg_hba.conf file two lines for both but no result.

Comment: Host and guest should be on the same network. Edit the VirtualBox configuration

Comment: @DeRipper for example, guest must have `192.168.56.15`

Comment: Yes, what I needed was to configure the adapters of the guest machine to connect to the Host-Only Network. Now the guest has the IP address `192.168.56.101` and by specifying it at the php script I could make the query to the database. Thank you.

Comment: @DeRipper I'm glad it helped. I've updated my answer. You should remove `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` from `pg_hba.conf` for secuirity reason. More details in the answer :)